# getItem method in viewpager called two times. How to avoid second time calling

Tags: android, android-viewpager

getItem() method called two times first time.I know this feature of view pager.According my requirement, I need to load one page at a time. If you know about that Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to see your implementations so that we can find the problem area of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `activity` or `fragment` is having `ViewPager`, you can implement `onPageChangedListener()` on that.

In that listener there's one method called `onPageSelected(int position)` which will give you position of your current page. You can use that method to call your `getItem()` method, so it will be executed only when the page will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

use [setOffscreenPageLimit(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29)

pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(7); // 7 means total number of pager items

Comment: *Not an answer*, please understand the question properly.